# How can I convert Hijri date to gregorian in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I would like convert this date:09/13/1436 (it is Hijiri) to 2015-06-30(it is Gregorian).
I tried  that:

```
function HijriToJD($m, $d, $y){
   return (int)((11 * $y + 3) / 30) + 354 * $y + 
     30 * $m - (int)(($m - 1) / 2) + $d + 1948440 - 385;
}


$date = HijriToJD(09, 13, 1436);

echo jdtogregorian($date);
```

and when i made compile i got 10/7/2014.
Someone have any idea??

Comment: maybe take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/ref.calendar.php Comment #4

Comment: can you tell what is date and month in `09/13/1436`?

Comment: 09 - > month,13->day,1436->year.

Comment: [how to convert hijri date to gregorian date using php](http://voidasks.com/how_to_convert_hijri_date_to_gregorian_date_using_php)

Comment: I made convert on website ,so i know it is must be 2015-06-30. So i dont know why i got 10/7/2014.

Comment: @john-conde - not really a duplicate of that John.... poster is having problems converting dates between __calendars__, not simply formats

Comment: @MarkBaker Fair enough. Reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing `09` as the month is the problem.... a number with a [leading zero](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) is treated as **octal** in PHP. `09` is invalid octal, so it is treated as a `0`.

Calling

```
$r=HijriToJD(9, 13, 1436);
```

(without the leading zero for the month) should give you a correct result

Comment: Yes!! Thanks you are my Hero.

Comment: I couldn't let you get the month wrong at such an important time of year could I? :)

Answer (score 1):

More accurate  will be

```
return floor((11 * $year + 3) / 30) + floor(354 * $year) + floor(30 * $month)
            - floor(($month - 1) / 2) + $day + 1948440 - 386;
```

You can use the floor instead of int

https://github.com/OpenSID/OpenSID/blob/master/donjo-app/libraries/Date_conv.php#L44