# How convert Hijri date to gregorian in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I got the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157323/how-can-i-convert-hijri-date-to-gregorian-in-php)

I have this date `1401/01/16`(Hijri Islamic) want to convert it to `24-11-1980` normal date.

Code:

```
function HijriToJD($m, $d, $y)
{
    return (int)((11 * $y + 3) / 30) + 354 * $y +
        30 * $m - (int)(($m - 1) / 2) + $d + 1948440 - 385;
}

$r = HijriToJD(1, 16, 1401);
    
date("Y-m-d", $r);

// output is: "1970-01-29" and it should be "1980-11-24"
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the name of that function suggests that it is converting to a Julian Date - a notation commonly used by astronomers, represented as a number of days from a fixed point. For use with `date()`, you want a Unix timestamp, which is a number of *seconds* from a completely different fixed point, so the function is entirely unsuitable, unless you combine it with another conversion from Julian Date to timestamp.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks I found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/RabeeaAli/c758cc9b46500f153eed73dc27fc87e9